# Actual way of sending http headers to the client in system.net.socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I use system.net.socket for listening on a port. Clients send request over XDomainRequest (IE9), socket handles their requests and sends response back.

Now I send response by two steps. Firstly I send headers like that:

```
string httpHeaders = "HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n";
httpHeaders += "Cache-Control: no-cache" + "\r\n";
httpHeaders += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
httpHeaders += "\r\n\r\n";

byte[] byteHttpHeaders = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(httpHeaders);

handler.BeginSend(byteHttpHeaders, 0, byteHttpHeaders.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
```

Then I send the other part of data like that:

```
byte[] byteData= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");

handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
```

But that way does not seem to be good. Rarely client cannot get response and when I look at my logs I see that he received only headers.

I tried to concatenate two byte arrays with blockcopy and send headers and other data at one time. But unfortunately this does not work. I cannot send anything to the client this way. I use blockcopy this way:

```
byte[] concat = new byte[byteHttpHeaders.Length + byteData.Length];

System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteHttpHeaders, 0, concat, 0, byteHttpHeaders.Length);

System.Buffer.BlockCopy(byteData, 0, concat, byteHttpHeaders.Length, byteData.Length);

handler.BeginSend(concat, 0, concat.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
```

Can I send all data at once? What is the best way of that?

Thanks

Comment: "and when I look at my logs I see that he received only headers." - well, you've only shown code that writes headers, so I'm not sure what you want us to say here. Nothing looks *too* broken here (I'm not sure I'd use UTF8, and you aren't setting a content length or type). When/where are you sending the payload? (Oh, and the string concatenation is very inefficient)

Comment: And to be clear: concatenating headers and payload should work just fine. If it isn't working: there's something broken in how you're doing it.

Comment: As an additional thought: do you really want to deal with the protocol details? HttpListener can deal with that for you, letting you concentrate on real code

Comment: So @MarcGravell is saying that you should combine the headers and payload in one byte[] and send that all at once.

Comment: @DWright well, not quite - I'm saying that you *can do that*, and that if done properly it should work fine.

Comment: @Marc I cannot use HttpListener because of security limitations.

Comment: @Marc: sorry for misrepresentation.  Indeed you were saying that Orkun *could* combine the headers into one send, not *should*.

Comment: The reason your blockcopy isn't working is that you are copying both of them to the *start* of the array. The 4th parameter is the offset in the destination array; on the second call, this should be `byteHttpHeaders.Length `

Comment: @Bekar "because of security limitations" - like what? I can assure you that HttpListener is going to be a lot more secure and robust than something you cobble together on Socket, since it seems this isn't your speciality area. This type of code is *hard* (trust me, I know: I wrote the custom web-socket server we use for stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Marc the users will use this application without administrator rights. So HttpListener does not allow them to listen ports. C# is my special area but of course I'm not professional as you :) Anyway... Thanks all of you.

Comment: @OrkunBekar while http.sys (what HttpListener uses under the hood) has restrictions, sockets *also* don't randomly allow you to listen to arbitrary ports, and *also* have restrictions (most noticeably: the OS firewall)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are sending twice (once headers, once body) via `BeginSend`, with the second `BeginSend` happening before the first `BeginSend` has completed. If you do that: the behaviour is undefined (you have violated the expected usage). It is expected that you will only have one outbound async operation at a time. If your code doesn't allow for that conveniently: *don't use async*: just use `Send`. Making use of *any* of the async socket APIs takes a lot of planning and attention to detail.

Comment: I have to use multi thread socket. So I suppose it sould be async right?

Comment: @Orkun quite possibly, but you still need to do it right... Which means only one pending send at a time (and only one pending receive)

Comment: is it possible to receive all data at once? I'm searching about that but I cannot find anything. Also could you look at my receiving style if it is right or not? I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602361/actual-way-of-receiving-data-in-system-net-socket

Comment: @OrkunBekar no; the inbound data is a stream; you can't tell if you've reached the end without: reading to the end! This is made much more complicated if you are implementing HTTP 1.1, obviously, due to keep-alives and connection re-use. In that scenario, you need to understand *framing*.