# Actual way of receiving data in system.net.socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I use multi threaded async socket for receiving data from XDomainRequest. I didn't have a problem about receiving data till now but I don't like my current way of doing that. So I wonder if there is a better idea.

Here is my StateObject:

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // stores total byte length which comes from XDomainRequest
    public int totalReceivedBuffer = 0;

    // stores byte lenght comes when each call of ReceiveCallBack
    public int receivedBuffer = 0;
}
```

In AcceptCallBack I create StateObject:

```
StateObject state = new StateObject();
state.workSocket = handler;
```

Then I have to do a weird thing to learn total received bytes:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);                 
state.totalReceivedBuffer = handler.Available;
```

If I don't put sleep, I get available value less than the actual value. In ReceiveCallBack method, I get received byte lenght for small part of data:

```
int numBytesReceived = handler.EndReceive(result);
```

I get StateObject which comes from AcceptCallBack and add that received bytes to it:

```
state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
handler = state.workSocket;

state.receivedBuffer += numBytesReceived;
```

then I control if it got equal to total bytes:

```
if(state.receivedBuffer == state.totalReceivedBuffer)
{
    // do the job
}
else
{
    // Call ReceiveCallBack again
}
```

Is there a better way of doing that?

**EDIT:**

I'm calling ReceiveCallBack at the end of AcceptCallBack like that:

```
handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

My ReceiveCallBack function is here. I cut some of it:

```
public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        StateObject state = null;
        Socket handler = null;

        try
        {
            state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
            handler = state.workSocket;

            string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

            //  See how many bytes received
            int numBytesReceived = handler.EndReceive(result);

            if (!handler.Connected)
            {
                handler.Close();
                return;
            }


            if (numBytesReceived > 0)
            {
                state.receivedBuffer += numBytesReceived;

                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, numBytesReceived));

                // Read all data line by line
                string[] lines = state.sb.ToString().Split('\n');

                if (state.receivedBuffer == state.totalReceivedBuffer)
                {
                    // All data came
                    // do the job according to lines array


                }
                else
                {
                    // continue receiving
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            // Don't care
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            #region SocketException

            if (ex.ErrorCode == 10054)
            {
                // HATA: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
                Globals.ErrorLogYaz(_log, Globals.GetCurrentMethod(), "Karşı taraf işlem tamamlanmadan bağlantıyı kapattı!", ex.StackTrace);

                handler.Close();
            }

            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.ErrorLogYaz(_log, Globals.GetCurrentMethod(), ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);

            handler.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted more complete sections of your program instead of a few lines from here and there. Anyway, if I understand right you're asking about reading data on a .Net Socket. There are lots of sample programs to be found on the Internet. But I agree that it is confusing since it can be done in many different ways, and the different sample programs may use the various different ways. For example using blocking calls or asynchronous calls, and then for .Net Framework 3.5 Microsoft introduced a new way, using SocketAsyncEventArgs, which is what they now recommend.

Comment: If you're willing to start all over again I can recommend this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

Comment: If you just want to improve your current code, then you are right in thinking that having Thread.Sleep() in your code is bad. What you need to do is to re-issue the asynchronous receive call from the callback method, and each tme the callback is called accumulate the additional bytes. And you need to be able to detect when you've received enough bytes to process what you've received, which depends on the protocol you're using. For example by "framing" each message by prefixing it with the number of bytes in the message.

Comment: Another tutorial for using SocketAsyncEventArgs: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22918/How-To-Use-the-SocketAsyncEventArgs-Class

Comment: @RenniePet thanks I will now look at the articles.

Comment: Without seeing the `BeginReceive`, it is impossible to comment on whether this is correct

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: So you don't have any actual problem, you just want to "improve" the code? Maybe you'd better post your question on CodeReview.SE :)

Comment: @Luaan Actually no :) I want to learn if this way of receiving data causes any problem or not.

Comment: Yup, that's a code review. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The way to read data from a connection is to actually call `Receive` and examine how many bytes you got. There is no way to predict how many will come. `Available` is the amount of data available *right now*. How could the receiver possibly know how much more the sender will send in the future? It can't know.

Call `Receive` in a loop until it returns 0 (the connection is closed) or until you know by some other means that all bytes are received.

Since you seem to be a beginner with sockets and there does not seem to be a reason to use async you probably should use synchronous IO. It is much simpler.

Comment: In some cases the application should allow simultaneous connections. What do you mean by future? User sends a request over XDomainRequest and it is catched in AcceptCallBack method. When I catch it handler.Available may be less then total amount for just that request?

Comment: TCP does not have requests or messages. It gives you a stream of bytes without boundaries. Accept does not nothing to receive data. You don't know the first thing about TCP. Please read a tutorial. This is very basic and you cannot do without this knowledge.