# Setting up 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for HTTP Listener

Tags: c#, ajax, sockets, web

I wanted a solution to send data from a C# application to a Web Page once a request was made to the C# application (via a AJAX post from the web page), then using the project implemented [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Requ), I wrote a simple console application to listen for ajax posts. It works great - I click on a button on my page that fires a AJAX post to `http://localhost:8081/`, which is the port the HTTP Listener is listening on, then the Listener Callback responds with some data back to the web page and I can use the data in the success function of the ajax post.

My problem - I need to open my webpage by using the URL `http://localhost:8081/index.html` which request the page from my IIS server, then only can I start my Listener and press the button to fire the AJAX because if I just keep my service running and navigate to the url my page doesnt show up but instead the data my Listener returns and not page IIS should serve. This happens becuase the port my Listener is listening on is the same one IIS is binding to when serving my page. So I decided to keep my IIS binding on port `8081` and just change my Listener to Listen on `8083` instead and let my ajax post to `8083` as well, that way I can keep my IIS service separate from the posts I'm doing to get data.

Here is my listener config:

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8083/");
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8083/");
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
```

And here is my AJAX Post

```
.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost:8008/',
      data: test_data,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {

        //Use data

      }
      });
```

This setup should work, only problem is when I now click the button I get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8083/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.`, which is to be expected, but I do not how to fix it.

As [Orkun Bekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4140498/orkun-bekar) pointed out, one can simply add  crossDomain: true, and dataType: 'jsonp' to the ajax post, and that works, I can reach my Listener now, but I still get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error when I try to send back some data.

Here is the part of my Listener call back that send back some data:

```
...
List<Byte> imgraw = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\USER\Pictures\image.jpg").ToList();
string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imgraw.ToArray());

byte[] imgDataArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data:image/jpg;base64," + base64ImageRepresentation);
byte[] responseConfigArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n\r\n");

byte[] buffer = new byte[responseConfigArray.Length + imgDataArray.Length];
responseConfigArray.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
imgDataArray.CopyTo(buffer, responseConfigArray.Length);

var response = context.Response;
response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
response.StatusCode = 200;
response.StatusDescription = "OK";
response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of sending the data and the headers in the `response.OutputStream`, I added it in the response.Headers Property.

```
...
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
...
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, but `"*"` is totaly unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

First you will create your response string including headers:

```
string responseConfigArray = "HTTP/1.1\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n\r\n";
string imgDataArray = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64ImageRepresentation;
```

Then convert it to byte array:

```
byte[] byteHttpHeaders = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseConfigArray);
byte[] concat = new byte[byteHttpHeaders.Length + imgDataArray.Length];

Buffer.BlockCopy(byteHttpHeaders, 0, concat, 0, byteHttpHeaders.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(imgDataArray, 0, concat, byteHttpHeaders.Length, imgDataArray.Length);
```

And send response data to web:

```
var response = context.Response;
response.ContentLength64 = concat.Length;
response.StatusCode = 200;
response.StatusDescription = "OK";
response.OutputStream.Write(concat, 0, concat.Length);
```

Comment: I get the '... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header...' error before the request can reach the Listener, when I initially make the Ajax post,so need to customize my headers at my web page side.

Comment: Try adding crossDomain: true, and dataType: 'jsonp' to your ajax post please.

Comment: It's working now, I can reach my Listener but now I can't send the data back to my because I am only sending back the data I need, not that "HTTP/1.1\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n\r\n". Is there a way to send both, or as one together?

Comment: Then you will concatenate two byte arrays and send them as a single byte array.

Comment: I Updated the post. Tried to concat the arrays, still no luck. New update includes code I use the respond

Comment: Try blockcopy as I do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580788/actual-way-of-sending-http-headers-to-the-client-in-system-net-socket). Also what exception do you get now? Don't you use data:image/jpg;base64  on your web part? May be it shouldn't be sent by listener?

Comment: BlockCopy might be a good solution, can I use it with the output.Write() in my code, where you use handler.Send()? Yes I would like to use that data in my page, that's what I want the listener to do, to wait for a call, then send back data.

Comment: If possible, can you show an exmple of how you would implement the Block Copy and sending using that last block of code my post.

Comment: I edited the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I first just tried to only send the header and not the data just to see of the C.O.R.S error is dealt with, but still no luck. I only sent the 'responseConfigArray' string that's converted to the byte[].

Comment: What is your Windows and IE version? If Windows 10 I will say it is normal because I still could not solve CORS on Windows 10.

Comment: Aah I see, yeah I'm also running Windows 10.